# Where do I find the samples referred to by Jetpack Compose source documentation?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kdoc

The KDoc contains links as to some package and Kotlin file, but I can't see such packages and files actually

[Documentation window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiDKx.png)

I looked through the Google Maven repository, expecting to find that I just haven't included some package in my `build.gradle`, but there were no such artifacts as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the samples by following package name in the AndroidX repository.

In this case `androidx.compose.foundation.layout.samples.SpacerExample` sample can be found [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/foundation/foundation-layout/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/samples/SpacerSample.kt).

As to KDoc problem, it's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19119)